# What happens if modulus is used in an 'if' statement?

Tags: c++

I'm wondering what would happen if we used modulus in this way:

```
if (input%2)
    more code here
```

I know modulus returns the remainder value, in this case, the remainder after the input has been divided by 2. But what determines in this case, if the code runs through the if statement or not?

Comment: What happens if `0` or a different value appears in an if statement?

Answer (score 5):

In a boolean context, a result of an expression that's zero is interpreted as a false value, and any non-zero result as a true value.

So, in this case, if the result of the modulus operator is not 0, the `if` expression evaluates to `true`.

Comment: I believe some C compilers/standards allow it to output `-1` if `input` is negative. But as far as truthiness goes, it doesn't matter, so odd numbers will result in truthy values, even numbers will produce falsy outputs.

Comment: Fair enough @ShadowRanger.

Comment: @ShadowRanger since C99 and C++11 , it is guaranteed that `-1 % 2 == -1`. In older versions it was implementation-defined.

Answer (score 1):

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

int main(){

    if(3%2){
        printf("True");   
    }else{
        printf("False");
    }

    printf("\n");

    if(2%2){
        printf("True");   
    }else{
        printf("False");
    }
}
```

Running this prints:

```
True
False
```

As @Sam described, the result of the `7%2` expression is `1`, and thus the conditional statement prints `True` (or does anything else inside that `if` statement).

Edit:

Adding to that, any non-zero value for the conditional statement will allow you to "get inside" the `if` statement:

```
if(13%5){
    printf("True");   
}else{
    printf("False");
}
```

Prints:

```
True
```